# Unable to Enable Elasticsearch Service in Google Cloud

Tags: elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform

I'm attempting to integrate Elasticsearch service on Google Cloud, but I'm encountering an issue where I cannot proceed as expected. According to the documentation, after subscribing to the Elasticsearch service on Google Cloud, an "ENABLE" button should appear on the Elasticsearch service page in Google Cloud, allowing me to proceed with the setup. However, instead of the "ENABLE" button, I see a different button, which does not allow me to move forward with the integration.

Has anyone faced this issue before? Could there be a step I'm missing, or is there a workaround to enable the Elasticsearch service on Google Cloud? Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I've followed all the preliminary steps recommended in the Google Cloud documentation for setting up the Elasticsearch service, including subscribing to the service. Unfortunately, the expected "ENABLE" button is not appearing. Here's a screenshot of the page I'm seeing (please note, attach the screenshot of the page here).

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfUlq.png)

The procedure that was supposed to happen.↓↓↓

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-essvYE4la8&t

Thank you in advance for your help!

postscript: my account is direct
[my account type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHwz2.png)

Comment: The only thing i can think of that would prevent you from moving forward is that your billing account is a reseller billing account. Meaning Elastic Search does not allow their products on a reseller billing ID.

Comment: So fix might be to use a regular billing ID.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!
my account type is direct, not reseller. I'll put up the screenshot as above.